# Setting up Philips Hue on Windows

Tags: windows, upnp, philips-hue, ssdp

I am trying to set Philips Hue on Windows 8.1 (64bit). However, I am not sure why when I browse to the following website it doesn't show anything:
https://www.meethue.com/api/nupnp

I have even tried the following (as some of their pages resides on www2.)
https://www2.meethue.com/api/nupnp

For now I cannot follow this tutorial
http://www.developers.meethue.com/documentation/hue-bridge-discovery

So as a matter of fact I wonder if there is a way I can control the Hue using Windows and write code using its SDK? I have hard time setting it.

I have already set it up with my phone and it works correctly.

Comment: Last two links are 'service unavailable'  and 'access denied'  (without login).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Philips Hue is platform independent, so your OS is not quite relevant here unless you're emulating. I don't have any experience with the SDK so I couldn't tell you what its features are.

https://www.meethue.com/api/nupnp for me yields the following response (on a network where a hue is available)

```
[{"id":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","internalipaddress":"x.x.x.x"}]
```

where x is private data that I'm not going to disclose here :P

On a network where no hue is available, a simple "[]" is returned for me.

It seems if your response is [], your hue bridge is either not properly connected to the internet or otherwise unable to connect to the meethue servers. Being properly set up on your phone does not necessarily indicate a proper connection to the servers.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to get the IP of your bridge by scanning your local network.

There are many tools which will do this for you, I would recommend an android app called "Fing".